# eclipse organize import not working with kotlin files

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

When I try to use the organize inputs in a Kotlin class, it does not add missing imports like in Java.

Specific case:

1. create a new Kotlin class file with the following contents: 
   `data class Foo (
       public var fileEncoding: String = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
   )`
2. Eclipse complains that it can't find StandardCharsets
3. use organize inputs, but StandardCharsets is not added to the import statements.

I would have expected that it added the line `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: since 0.7.0 Kotlin Eclipse plugin supports [organize imports](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/06/kotlin-eclipse-plugin-0-7-is-here/).

At present, Kotlin Eclipse plugin does not support "Organize imports" feature: [KT-3962](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3962). Please feel free to upvote for this issue.

For now, you can try to invoke quick fix action (**Ctrl+1**) to import *StandardCharsets* class.